# Group policy settings not apply to windows 10

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-10

I'm using Windows Server 2008 r2 and different client workstation platform in Windows. But I have an issue which the GPO's is not updating in some of my Windows 10 pro workstation clients.

Kindly help to sort out this issue.

Comment: Please share the gpo that dont update, as in example some GPO are depreciated, like IE maintenance. As such newer workstation would not get it, while older on the network yes.

Comment: as far as I remember, there was a bug in W10, that was causing this issue. Here's the link to one of the threads about this 
 https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a20e3f6-728a-4aa9-831a-6133f446ea08/gpos-do-not-apply-on-windows-10-enterprise-x64?forum=winserverGP

Comment: thanks buddy i already referred that, they mention to " disable the UNC hardening for netlogon and sysvol Shares in the registry." to do that its not working if your familiar in this kindly reply pls...

Answer (score 1):

If its possible, try to run gpresult /h "path to exportedfile\file.html in the client computer to see what policies the computer gets:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160(v=ws.11).aspx

Other is group policy modeling from the group policy management console:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771389(v=ws.11).aspx